# Need to parse a double entry table with two pairs

Tags: sed, grep, awk, perl

I have this two-entry table resulting from a program output:

```
Variable1  : Value1  
Variable2  : Value2  
Variable3  : Value3  
Variable4  : Value4  
Variable5  : Value5  
Variable6  : Value6  
Variable7  : Value7
```

I need to extract both the first and the fifth pairr\s, something I do with grep:

```
$ {program command} | grep -e Variable1 -e Variable5
```

resulting in this output:

```
Variable1  : Value1  
Variable5  : Value5
```

The problem here is that I need both pairs on the *same* line but the grep -e command prints a LF/CR after every -e; I need the four pairs in the same line to make a final sort based on file size. I think I could make this in awk or perl from the same command line but alas I'm still somewhat green with them.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to join the lines use `tr` to delete the newline:

```
$ {program command} | grep -e Variable1 -e Variable5 | tr -d '\n'
```

To do the whole thing in `awk`:

```
$ {program command} | awk '/Variable[15]/ { printf("%s ", $0) }'
```

Same in `sed`:

```
$ {program command} | sed -n '/Variable[15]/H; $ { x; s/\n/ /g; p }'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want join both lines from grep, the easiest way is to pipe through `fmt`.

```
$ {program command} | grep -e Variable1 -e Variable5 | fmt
```

If the lines are too long, use the `-w LINELENGTH` option of fmt.

Comment: I never used `fmt` before so thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the newline by Perl's substitution

```
perl -ne 's/\n/ /; print if /Variable[15]/'
```

If you need a newline at the end, add

```
perl -ne 's/\n/ /; print if /Variable[15]/ }{ print "\n"'
```